# throw error after everything is rendered in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a react HOC that would render its children, and then after *all* the children had finished updating BUT BEFORE THE DOM is updated, would decide to raise (or not raise) an error, depending on some flags the children would update.

```
<Try alternative=... >
  ... do some stuff // if anybody in here sets a flag we will
                    // render alternative instead
</Try>
```

Why?  It would be useful to allow all the children of Try to complete rendering and then if any were waiting on some async callbacks, to render the alternative.  Kind of like an error boundary but it would all the enclosed children to re-rerender first.

Having the first child that hits the condition raise an error doesn't work, since it doesn't allow the rest of the children to finish.

Using an componentDidUpdate handler in Try won't work either, since it won't run unless Try actually changed (I think).

I am hoping somebody will know of a secret, or expermental trick that might work.

Thanks

Comment: If any of the children are waiting on async callbacks; then, won't their state update when the async callback come backs? In which case that child would re-render itself.

Comment: yes that is correct.  My hope for this TRY component is to have a way to globally render a "spinner" or please wait type of cover across all the UI components, rather than have each individual component deal with it on its own.  So once the promises resolved, yes the state would update, and the children would rerender but now the alternative render in the try would not be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating things. Why not take a simple approach that achieves the same goal?

Your callbacks will set some sort of state. So that means, if the state has not been set, the callback has not been run.

In your child components you can check to see in the state has been set. If the state has not been set; then, display your "Please Wait" message.

The "Please Wait" message can be extracted into its own component and be used throughout the entire website. By extracting the code for the "please wait" cover, all components can then use it instead of implementing their own version of the "please wait" cover.

I think this is a lot more simply and effective then what you are suggesting.

EDIT:

Regarding the flickering mentioned in comments. That shouldn't happen. Where I was trying to go is have a "Cover" component for the "Please Wait".

The child component would check it's state to see if it is ready to display it's main content. If not, the child component would use the Cover component.

In otherwords:

1. Child Component is constructed
2. Child Component's State is not ready. Child uses Cover component
3. Child Component's State changes (due to async callback)
4. Child Component Starts Re-Render Process
5. Child Component's State is ready to render main content
6. Child Component renders its own content

This is fundamentally different from what your comment had said. The parent would not render the Cover. The child would use the Cover component when it is not ready to render its own content.

Comment: what you say is partly true if you were doing this once, but the point is to build a reusable container component.  We have a fairly large complicated set of apps, and having a single reusable component that takes of details makes it worth the pain of figuring out how to make it work.  Also the solution you propose does not work perfectly for a couple of reasons, the biggest is that you will get a short flicker, as the child components set state after they have rendered, then the parent will put of the covering please wait.

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn Hmmm, so the key functionality is creating reusable component that handles both checking if the cover should be rendered instead of the actual component, and rendering the content?